# Getting clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) when using code runner in VSCode on Ubuntu System

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, clang, vscode-code-runner

The program is structured as follows:

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../include/test.h"

int main(){
    moo();
    return 0;
}
```

**test.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../include/test.h"

void moo(){
    printf("moo\n");
}
```

**test.h:**

```
#ifndef MOO_HEADER
#define  MOO_HEADER

void moo();

#endif
```

The directory structure is as follows:
1)proj2
1.1)include
1.1.1)test.h
1.2)src
1.2.1)main.c
1.2.2)test.c

The command that is executed on running using code runner is:

```
cd "/home/saumya/Desktop/cProj/proj2/src/" && clang-12 main.c -o main && "/home/saumya/Desktop/cProj/proj2/src/"main
```

The error message looks like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-6d60a6.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `moo'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Would be grateful for any inputs.

The code works completely fine if instead of including the test.h header file I directly include the test.c file but if I am not wrong that is not the best method to use #include while coding.

Comment: `clang-12 main.c test.c -o main`

Comment: @CGi03 thanks I made the change in the settings.json file and this worked but it is only specific to the above-mentioned program. Any suggestions on what I could do if I also wish to run other programs using code runner?

Comment: Is there maybe any code runner configuration for compiling and linking multiple/all the .c files?

Comment: You need to compile and link all source files that provide the required functions or variables. If you have another program with different files, you must adjust accordingly.